# What is the default rounding mode of string formatter in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> '%f'%0.8407745
'0.840774'
>>> '%f'%0.8407755
'0.840776'
>>> '%f'%-0.8407755
'-0.840776'
>>> '%f'%-0.8407745
'-0.840774'
```

The results look weird. It is sometimes floor and sometimes ceil.
What is the default rounding mode of string formatter in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point numbers are always an approximation. `0.8407745` is not *exactly* `0.8407745`:

```
>>> '%.53f' % 0.8407745
'0.84077449999999998020427938172360882163047790527343750'
```

So the default formatter, rounding to 6 decimals, correctly rounds that value to `0.840774`.

`0.8407755` on the other hand is:

```
>>> '%.53f' % 0.8407755
'0.84077550000000000895994389793486334383487701416015625'
```

and should thus be rounded *up*.

See [The Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) for a good introduction as to why that is. (Summary: floating point numbers are represented by the sum of binary fractions).

Comment: So it makes more sense to round float value before format to string.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The formatting takes care of proper rounding of the value. Rounding first won't make a difference here.

Answer (score 2):

As per this [`table here`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), by default `%f` will have only 6 digit precision. So, the data is rounded off to 6 digits after the decimal point.

Quoting from the notes section of that table

> The alternate form causes the result to always contain a decimal
>   point, even if no digits follow it.
>
> The precision determines the number of digits after the decimal point
>   and defaults to 6.